# MSSM interactions

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, higgs, mssm

I have seen many pictures of fermion-boson interactions. But none of them are related to gravitons and MSSM particles.
*Do gravitons interact with photons, gluons and other particles?
What about the 4 other theoretical higgs?*
What about their SUSY partners?
Do SUSY particles interact with non-SUSY particles?

Edit: I've forgotten to tell you that I'm very, very new to supersymmetry. However I've read a few articles that have cleared some doubts(which are in italic) and made newer ones:

1. The MSSM has 2 higgs doublets one gives mass to up type particles and one to down type particles but why are there five? ($H^0_u,H^0_d,H^+,H^-,A^0$)
2. How do the interaction terms look like?

Comment: of course they do. Everything participates in gravitational interactions, so gravitons would interact with any particle. You can derive these interactions by applying QFT methods to GR and assuming some cutoff scale where new physics presumably appears.

Comment: What are the interactions of the theoretical higgs bosons?

Comment: I know that the charged higgs bosons interact with photons but that is all I know

Comment: Wait, do the charged higgs bosons interact with photons?

Comment: yes, if they have electric charge, it means they participate in electromagnetic interactions. And photon is the mediator of EM interactions

Comment: Do you have other information on the charged higgs bosons?

Comment: See chapter 8.1 of Martin's Supersymmetry Primer https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356 for some details about Higgs boson in SUSY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, of course. In the MSSM sector, you can observe fermion-boson interactions. If you pick up any MSSM phenomenological paper or reviews there you can see how the interactions are fabricated. In the below link you can find the gauge interactions in MSSM sectors.

https://indico.cern.ch/event/260403/attachments/459429/636636/Athron_SUSY-Cairns.pdf

2. The graviton-photon interaction can be explained by the gravitational Compton scattering. The attached PRD paper is very useful in this regard.

https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.91.064008

3. The interactions of other charged and neutral Higgs and the SUSY partner can be explained by their gauge and yukawa interactions.

Comment: What about the 4 types of higgs that the MSSM?

Comment: Those higgs can interact with the fermions through yukawa interactions and the interaction with the boson can be understood by guage interactions.

Comment: I did not understand point 3

Comment: How to charged higgs interact? DO they interact with themselves, photons and/or particles with mass and the graviton?

Comment: How does the h and A higgs interact? How are they different from the H and H-/+ bosons?

Comment: I don't how the graviton interacts with charged higgs. In MSSM sector, you can find the interactions in the attached article.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjc/s10052-016-4584-9.pdf